# MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() - how does it works

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this question: I have a stored procedure which inserts row to table A which has auto increment column a, and then inserts a row to table B which has a foreign key b to column A.a. I am using `LAST_INSERT_ID` to get column a value of the newly inserted row. But lat's say there are 2 parallel calls to this stored procedure, how can I make sure (or the DB itself makes sure) that there won't be any wrong assignment of column b.

Couldn't find this in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

Comment: It's per session basis. One session cannot have 'parallel' calls, they will always be in sequence (and you will not be bothered by any other sessions using auto-increment values). So in short: you can rely on it, the DB itself takes care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks @wrikken post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() function gets the last ID inserted by the same instance of the connection your using, so even if you have 1000 instances of the same script running at once you don't have to worry about it.